# order of appearance of authors in bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies

Im trying to have the bibliography defined for my document using BibTeX and the `natbib` citation management package. Styles such as `unsrtnat` give me the references in order of appearance in text. However, I have a problem that I cannot get around. Basically if a reference is supposed to look like:

> Tyson J.P. Dikstra M. Holmes F.M.R. Theoretical Analysis on Effect of
>   Anomalous Low Friction. International journal of Placticity,
>   34(3-4):413, 1997.

after typesetting it appears as :

> Dikstra M. Holmes F.M.R. Tyson J.P. Theoretical Analysis on Effect of
>   Anomalous Low Friction. International journal of Placticity,
>   34(3-4):413, 1997.

In other words, it puts the first author in the last place. Is there any method of getting around this?

The entry as it appears in the .bib file (`refs.bib`) is:

```
@ARTICLE{Tyson1997,
author={Tyson, J.P., Dikstra, M., Holmes, F.M.R.},
title={Theoretical Analysis on Effect of Anomalous Low Friction.},
journal={International journal of Plasticity},
year={1997},
volume={34},
number={3-4},
pages={413},
document_type={Article}
}
```

An excerpt from the tex file:

```
\usepackage[round,comma]{natbib}
\begin{document}

As an alternative method of analysis, \citet{Tyson1997} ...

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this just an alphabetically sorted list of authors rather than "[putting] the first author in the last place"?

Comment: @werner: I checked other entries as well. At first I thought it is sorting the family names alphabetically but that is not the case. It just throws the first author to the last place in the row and I really have no idea why.
If I use other bibliography styles such as "achemso" , it fixes the problem but then , apart from the first author, all others will have both their fist/last family names abbreviated which I am not happy with that. (By the way, I am using MikTeX 2.9 for the typesetting).

Answer (score 6):

You are probably using a bad syntax for the author names:

```
author={Tyson, J. P. and Dikstra, M. and Holmes, F. M. R.},
```

is the correct input so that BibTeX can parse the list of authors. I get the same output as you obtain with

```
author={Tyson J.P., Dikstra M. and Holmes F.M.R.},
```

that BibTeX parses, according to its rules, as *two* authors: the first has a family name "Tyson J.P.", first name "Dikstra" and middle name "M.". The second author has first name "Holmes" and family name "F.M.R.".

With your input

```
author={Tyson, J.P., Dikstra, M., Holmes, F.M.R.},
```

things are worse, because BibTeX finds too many commas and issues nine error messages.

Authors should be listed separated by the keyword `and`; you have the choice of listing each author as

```
<first name> <middle name(s)> <family name>
```

or in the clearer way

```
<family name>, <first name> <middle name(s)>
```